# separate columns for separate id fields?

Tags: sql, database, database-design

Say we have tables A, B, and C and then we want table Z to contain column `TYPE` which tells us which table of A, B, and C the record in Z is associated with.

Is it better to have a separate column for each table like columns `A_ID`, `B_ID`, and `C_ID` in order to use indexing?

Or is there some reason why using a generic column `TYPE_ID` might be better performance-wise?

Comment: I would not worry about performance but correctness. How are you going to join the tables - with dynamic SQL looking up the table name? What you are trying to do is not well supported in SQL. I would try to avoid the whole situation all together. But if you have to, Z should have foreign references, the only reason being that is what z holds - references to foreign keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a type_id and then a fk_id won't be good because selectivity on the index is 33%, which is too high to be of any use.  You would always be indexing on the fk_id instead (that which links to A,B,C) - which may require tie breaking between 3 values (if the id is used by all 3 types).

Storage wise, an index never stores nulls, so the absolute number of items stored in the indexes, whether a single (fk_id) or multiple (a_id,b_id,c_id) will be similar.

If you are coming in from the exact fk_id (from either A,B,C), then using a unique index on (fk_id,type_id) in that order can quickly identify the record required.

It would seem for simplicity and brevity, two columns are better than 3 here.

Answer (score 1):

This is sometimes a schema code smell.

If you are considering putting this as a single column in Z, does that mean that only one of A, B, C can be applicable to Z?

Before I decide, I'd really say I have to know more about the entity and the usage pattern.  Is access coming from known A, B, or C, or is the supplemental info driven from the Z side?  If it is driven from the Z side, do you want to get all the A, B and C columns and then use them selectively from the application, or just Zs with As or Zs with Bs - i.e. do you usually know the subtype?  Also, do A, B, and C have enough columns to merit the separation out of Zs row if they are each 1-1 (i.e. you could have the columns in Z and just be NULL)

Just for completeness, another possibility which gives you more referential integrity (because with a single column, you can't be an FK to one of three tables) is to have tables Z_A, Z_B, Z_C:

With schemas:

```
Z_A:
Z_ID REFERENCES (Z.ID)
A_ID REFERENCES (A.ID)

Z_B:
Z_ID REFERENCES (Z.ID)
B_ID REFERENCES (B.ID)

Z_C:
Z_ID REFERENCES (Z.ID)
C_ID REFERENCES (C.ID)
```

With all IDs unique in each table, this constrains everything pretty nicely, except there is nothing declarative to stop Z lying in multiple tables without a trigger (you cannot make a unique constraint on an indexed view over a UNION ALL in SQL Server).

While it seems to multiply the number of tables, these can usually be wrapped up into views.

Comment: +1 for schema code smell. Although maybe just schema smell is good enough

Comment: "If you are considering putting this as a single column in Z, does that mean that only one of A, B, C can be applicable to Z?" each a,b,c record can have 0+ associated z records

Comment: @Erik Void - I'm more confused now.  It sounds like an A row can also have no associated Z row, so the idea of going from Z to (A, B, C) makes little sense.  I need to understand more about the actual meaning of the tables - what is being modelled?

Comment: @Erik Void Why would you ever need to go from Z back to A, B, C, then?  I would simply have an anonymous integer ID from A, B, or C in Z, because it sounds like you are always going from A, B, or C to Z.  I'm not sure why Z would need to know where it came from - would you ever get a Z without some context?

Comment: We are using an A, B, C ID to find zero or many records in Z.

Comment: We also want to find the say 10 most recent comment threads (so Zs) then get the associated A, B, or C information..

Comment: @Erik I think I would use the 3 link tables design, then.  With appropriate indexes (both ways), they are very narrow and should perform well combined with a TOP to do the reverse lookup.

Comment: hmm that does sound appropriate.